# What Android phone can install unmovable apps on SD card?

Tags: android, smartphones, data-storage, microsd

Many heavy apps which plays an important role in productivity are unmovable to SD card by default: Word, Google Maps, Google Sheet, Tick Tick, Dropbox, OneDrive. I've tried to follow [Is there a way to move unmovable apps to the SD card in Android 6.0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/150583/94084) on my current phone (Sony E2312, Android 6.0.1, rooted and xposed) and failed to success, but I can't remember why because it has been a long time ago.

I understand the risk of this (removing the memory card, can't use widgets), but the need to use them is large. Which phone and Android version allow me to install **any** app on the card, or at least transfer a large portion of data onto it?

<sup>[This question is also asked on Reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/PickAnAndroidForMe/comments/7wiqye/what_phone_can_install_unmovable_apps_on_sd_card/?ref=share&ref_source=link)</sup>

Comment: I am thinking that this should be asked on [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as the phone itself doesn't control that; the OS does. Any phone that has an SD card slot running that OS will work, as long as that OS supports the phone.